# Ledger Nano S on Arch Linux - Chrome app will not recognize device

Tags: arch-linux, bitcoin

I am running Arch Linux 64 bit - 4.13.8-1

I tried Ledger's [fix](https://ledger.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/ledger-wallet-is-not-recognized-on-linux) by adding udev rules and changing owner:

```
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1b7c", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2b7c", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3b7c", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4b7c", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1807", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1808", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"
"OWNER="USER", KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97"
"OWNER="USER", KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581"ess", TAG+="udev-acl"
```

HW File:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER users 1386 Oct 28 13:43 20-hw1.rules
```

The device does show up with dmesg -w:

```
hid-generic 0003:2C97:0001.003A: hiddev1,hidraw9: USB HID v1.11 Device [Ledger Nano S] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
```

Yet I cannot get the Ledger Manager or Wallet to recognize my Ledger.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Same here: uname -> running 4.13.11-1-ARCH . Ledger Nano S not recognized on ArchLinux, despite following documentation : here are example udev rules and dmesg -w output : https://pastebin.com/1xANhLQW

Comment: It worked once I've changed MODE to 0666 , so it looks like it can be something with priviledges. Maybe on your and mine distros it should be different GROUP="" to make it work with 0660, like e.g. "users".

Comment: Falstart -> Ledger Manager seems to partially work, but not Bitcoin or Ethereum Wallet Apps... Trezor started smoothly, while Ledger Nano, not that much (maybe it's not fail of software but I just encountered not authentic one?) -> continuing investigation.

Comment: Finally made it work! I had to :

* reinstall chrome app Ledger Manager: https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165189-What-if-the-synchronisation-lasts-too-long-
* with it , uninstall Bitcoin, Ethereum and other apps and install again on Ledger Devide
* finally Ledger Wallet worked! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ledger-wallet-bitcoin/kkdpmhnladdopljabkgpacgpliggeeaf/related and Ethereum one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ledger-wallet-ethereum/hmlhkialjkaldndjnlcdfdphcgeadkkm/related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the term "app" is used for two different things. There are:

- the chrome apps which run on your browser (duh...)
- the ledger apps which run on the USB.

Not much we can do... Anyway.

1. Do not install any of the Chrome apps. If you already installed some of them uninstall them.
2. Create the following file. Do take note that you need to replace the value of the `GROUP` attribute with a group that your user belongs to. On Archlinux, if you follow the Install guide, a group with the same name as your user should exist. That's what you should use. On other distros, it might be something like `users`.

   ```
   $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/20-hw1.rules

   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1b7c", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2b7c", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3b7c", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4b7c", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1807", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1808", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", MODE="0660", GROUP="replace_with_your_user_name"
   ```
3. Install the [Ledger Wallet Manager](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/apps/manager). This is a chrome app and you use it to update the firmware on the USB.
4. Start the Manager app. You will see a list of ledger apps which you can install on your wallet. Delete the existing ones (BTC and ETH) and reinstall them. You can now use your wallet.
5. Install the [Ledger Wallet BTC App](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/apps/bitcoin). This is the chrome app you use to make transactions.
6. Install additional Ledger Wallet apps (e.g. the [ETH one](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/apps/ethereum)).

Answer (score 1):

LINUX DOES NOT RECOGNIZE LEDGER NANO S - SOLVED

I struggled with this for months and finally found a fix that works every time. I thought some kernel updates had finally fixed the problem for good, but I noticed that after one reboot, the machine couldn't see my nano again.

THE FIX: It's so stupid, you'll smack yourself (if it works for you, that is). I'm assuming you've tried everything else already, and that you've run the script from Ledger that adds the udev rules, etc, etc.

Step 1: Plug in your nano to the PC's USB port and unlock it by entering your pin. Leave it unlocked and go to step 2 right away.

Step 2: Reboot the pc  (the computers I've tested this on kept the nano powered through a reboot, so I think this is necessary)

Step 3:Try the Chrome apps/MEW now.

When I noticed that the lsusb command gave different results when the device was locked compared to when it was unlocked, I thought of how Linux sometimes needs to boot up with a USB peripheral plugged in to get it to recognize correctly. This didn't occur to me, because the nano WAS plugged in... EVERY TIME I WAS STRUGGLING WITH THIS - IT WAS PLUGGED IN...... just not unlocked during reboot every time. I assume this is also why my testing kept giving me different results - sometimes I was rebooting with the Nano unlocked, sometimes when is was locked... but always plugged in - this is what threw me off the scent of the solution.